# Weird Go Regular Expression mismatch when routing http requests

Tags: regex, go

I'm serving web content via a Go web server and using regular expressions to match handlers to request paths. I've noticed a really strange behaviour I've diluted to this test code below. 
Basically, any 8 letter/number combination is meant to be caught by a handler, while other specific request paths are meant to be caught by other handlers. This works great by in the case of the 8 letter/number path the match gets picked up by the first handler if the letter sequence ends in a lower case 'c'. Any other letter at the end works fine.

The code below can be pasted into a file and run. It will serve on localhost:8080. I've provided a few request links to demonstrate the problem.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http" 
    "regexp"
) 

// This is the handler when passing a string of 8 characters ([])
func runTest(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    path := r.URL.Path[1:]
    fmt.Fprintf(w, path)
} 

func runTest2(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    path := "Reg ex for: .[(css|jpg|png|js|ttf|ico)]$" 
    fmt.Fprintf(w, path)
} 

func runTest3(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    path := "Reg ex for: /all$" 
    fmt.Fprintf(w, path)
} 

// Regular expression handler
type route struct {
    pattern *regexp.Regexp
    handler http.Handler
}

type RegexpHandler struct {
    routes []*route
}

func (h *RegexpHandler) Handler(pattern *regexp.Regexp, handler http.Handler) {
    h.routes = append(h.routes, &route{pattern, handler})
}

func (h *RegexpHandler) HandleFunc(pattern *regexp.Regexp, handler func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request)) {
    h.routes = append(h.routes, &route{pattern, http.HandlerFunc(handler)})
}

func (h *RegexpHandler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    for _, route := range h.routes {
        if route.pattern.MatchString(r.URL.Path) {
            route.handler.ServeHTTP(w, r)
            return
        }
    }
    http.NotFound(w, r)

}

func main() {
    handler := &RegexpHandler{} 
     handler.HandleFunc(regexp.MustCompile(`.[(css|jpg|png|js|ttf|ico)]$`), runTest2)
     handler.HandleFunc(regexp.MustCompile("^/all$"), runTest3) 
    handler.HandleFunc(regexp.MustCompile("^/[A-Z0-9a-z]{8}$"), runTest)  
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", handler)
}
```

This request gets picked up by the second handler (runTest3):

```
http://localhost:8080/all
```

This request gets picked up by the third handler (runTest) which prints out the path portion of the url:

```
http://localhost:8080/yr22FBMD.
```

This request however, gets picked up by the first handler (note its ending with a lower case c):

```
http://localhost:8080/yr22FBMc
```

Any ideas? This is extremely weird!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have the extensions inside brackets in runTest2. This makes it a character class so your regex is saying, "match any line with '(' 'c', 's', '|', 'j', 'p', 'g', 'n', 't', 'f', 'i', 'o', or ')' as the last character.

You just need to remove the sqaure brackets, and I think you mean to escape the period at the beginning.

```
"\.(css|jpg|png|js|ttf|ico)$"
```

Comment: Thank you! I don't think I would have spotted those brackets in a million years...